# Wrong UITapGestureRecognizer being called (in the wrong UIView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've got a ViewController which contains a vertical UIScrollView. To said UIScrollView I add multiple subviews, each of which contains a horizontal UIScrollView which contains some images and is paged.

When creating these subviews, I add a UITapGestureRecognizer to their UIScrollViews to detect single taps on them and perform an action depending on which image was being displayed.

The problem I've got is that if I have 2 such subviews and tap the first one in line, it picks up the wrong subview and tries to fire the method on the second one. So, say I tapped the 3rd image of the 1st subview, and the 2nd subview only has 1 page, then the app crashes.

Here's the constructor for my subview:

```
- (id)init {

    NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GalleryLeafView"
                                                      owner:nil
                                                    options:nil];
    GalleryLeafView *galleryLeafView = [arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0];
    self = galleryLeafView;

    if (self) {

        // Set up tap gesture recognizers on the ScrollView
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped)];
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Here's the selector method, just in case:

```
- (void)imageTapped {

    NSString *filename = [imageFilenames objectAtIndex:[self getCurrentPage]];
    NSString *caption = [captions objectAtIndex:[self getCurrentPage]];

    [self.galleryLeafViewDelegate galleryLeafViewPressedWithFilename:filename caption:caption];
}
```

Any ideas as to why this happens? Or how I can work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was a yet another of my rookie mistakes ;/

In the selector method you can see I'm doing stuff on `imageFilenames` and `captions` arrays. They should've been strong properties, not just variables set in the .m file. Everything works fine now.